# Using vanilla JS selectors with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a minimal d3 line chart example with which I would like replace the d3 selectors for vanilla js selectors.
The below shows my attempt, with working d3 code commented out below my vanilla js version. It does successfully create the all the expected SVG elements, but they are not rendered to the screen properly so there is no chart.

```
const data = [
  { date: "Wed, 14 Aug 2019 00:00:00 GMT", close: 2.9254177545691844 },
  { date: "Wed, 28 Aug 2019 00:00:00 GMT", close: 2.8956143512450847 },
  { date: "Fri, 30 Aug 2019 00:00:00 GMT", close: 2.8878846468949795 },
  { date: "Mon, 02 Sep 2019 00:00:00 GMT", close: 2.893494826736734 },
];
data.forEach(d => (d.date = new Date(d.date)));

const margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 50 };
const width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
const x = d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
  .range([0, width]);
const y = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.close))
  .range([height, 0]);

// create line generator
const valueline = d3
  .line()
  .x(d => x(d.date))
  .y(d => y(d.close));

// add svg and g with vanilla js
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const svg = document.createElement("svg");
svg.setAttribute("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);
svg.setAttribute("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
const g = document.createElement("g");
g.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
svg.appendChild(g);
body.appendChild(svg);

// add svg and g with d3
// d3.select("body")
//   .append("svg")
//   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
//   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
//   .append("g")
//   .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Add lines
const g2 = d3.select("g");
g2.append("path")
  .data([data])
  .attr("d", valueline)
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("fill", "none");

// Add the Axes
g2.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
g2.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to specify the name space since SVG namespace is different than HTML's. We need to use [document.createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) to create SVG elements:

```
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
const g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
```

If we drop that into your code block we should successfully draw the graph:

```js
const data = [
  { date: "Wed, 14 Aug 2019 00:00:00 GMT", close: 2.9254177545691844 },
  { date: "Wed, 28 Aug 2019 00:00:00 GMT", close: 2.8956143512450847 },
  { date: "Fri, 30 Aug 2019 00:00:00 GMT", close: 2.8878846468949795 },
  { date: "Mon, 02 Sep 2019 00:00:00 GMT", close: 2.893494826736734 },
];
data.forEach(d => (d.date = new Date(d.date)));

const margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 50 };
const width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
const x = d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.date))
  .range([0, width]);
const y = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.close))
  .range([height, 0]);

// create line generator
const valueline = d3
  .line()
  .x(d => x(d.date))
  .y(d => y(d.close));

// add svg and g with vanilla js
//*
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
svg.setAttribute("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);
svg.setAttribute("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
const g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
g.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
svg.appendChild(g);
body.appendChild(svg);
//*/
// add svg and g with d3
/*
 d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
//*/
// Add lines
const g2 = d3.select("g");
g2.append("path")
  .data([data])
  .attr("d", valueline)
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("stroke-width",1)
  .attr("fill", "none");

// Add the Axes
g2.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
g2.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```